# Creating a violins edging

Tags: modeling

So far I created the violins outline.  I notice the front and back have a rounded edging.  How would I create this?  Is there a modifier I can use?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another "lazy" method is to double your geometry with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (so you can work with it later) and turn it into a curve, then give it a bevel like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

*(Curves provided by the eye tortured Quellenform...)*

Comment: Ouch, that hurts my eyes :D ...would you please be so kind, and could repeat that with this, especially for you created template? https://blend-exchange.com/b/YDxSRrqo/ ...you would be doing me (and others) a huge favor by doing this! 

Comment: Ah, wonderful! Now the thing sounds like a Stradivarius!

Comment: @quellenform: you definitely have too much time... :D

Comment: *"you definitely have too much time"* ...says the one who hangs around here all the time, answering one question after another :D

Comment: this was true a few month ago...but the moderators made me shorten my time here drastically.... ;)

Comment: What's 'Lazy' about that? I'd describe it as 'correct' (maybe using a custom curve for the profile..)  :) The face and the trim are separate objects. So, unless for 3D printing, or suchlike, they're better modelled as separate objects.

Comment: thank you Robin! I appreciate that!

Comment: The only problem with this is, the curve already has the outline of the violin - so to keep the shape with a bevel depth of 0.012 you have to set the geometry's offset to -0.012, which gives you shading issues because of overlapping geometry.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann : and where do you see the bevel depth of the curve of the OP?

Comment: @Chris I'm not talking about bevel depth, it doesn't matter which depth you choose - but I can see (and if you don't trust my eyes, use an image editor to overlay the curve on the reference image) that the curve is the outline of the violin including the rim. And the bevel depth of a curve is always going around the curve, so it extends the outline if you don't use the offset. The only problem as I said earlier: on those quite narrow parts you get shading issues, and depending on the bevel depth you get them no matter if you use the offset or not.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  Now im going to make the thin black line between the body and edging.  How do I resize my shape smaller by equal distance instead of the usual resize?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. Please open a new question if you have further questions. You can ask as many questions as you want, but only one question is allowed per entry. Which also makes sense so people can find the answers by the title.

Comment: Done, and TY fill out comment...

Answer (score 3):

From a single edge you can use the *Skin* modifier, and put a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to round it:

[image]

If you have filled the faces, you can do it with some extrusions. Begin with these two edges on top and side:

[image]

Extrude up then extrude on the side:

[image]

[image]

Pull and scale some edges to make it round:

[image]

Comment: I would also mention how edges of an object can be scaled uniformly if the object is not circular...

Comment: Yes, the question is a bit vague though...